# prevent typos in variable keyword args

Tags: python, python-2.x, variadic-functions, keyword-argument

In Python3 I can do (thanks to [pep 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)):

```
def some_fun(a, *args, log=None, verbose=0):
    pass
```

and be sure that if I call this with:

```
some_fun(1, 2, 3, lob=debug_log)
```

I get a type error on the unexpected keyword argument `lob`.

On Python2 I cannot define `some_fun()` with keyword-only arguments after an arbitrary argument list. I have to do:

```
def some_fun(a, *args, **kw):
    log  = kw.get("log", None)
    verbose = kw.get("verbose", 0)
```

this works all fine and dandy when called correctly, but I would like to get a type error just as with Python3 when I provide one or more wrong keyword arguments to `some_fun()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.get()` to retrieve the values, use `.pop()` and check if `kw` is empty after popping all keyword-only arguments.

I use a small helper function for this:

```
def check_empty_kwargs(kwargs):
   import inspect
   try:
      keys = kwargs.keys()
      assert len(keys) == 0
   except AssertionError:
      # uncomment if you want only one of the unexpected kwargs in the msg
      # keys = keys[:1]
      msg = "{0}() got an unexpected keyword argument{1} {2}".format(
         inspect.stack()[1][3], # caller name
         's' if len(keys) > 1 else '',
         ', '.join(["'{0}'".format(k) for k in keys]))
      raise TypeError(msg)
```

And you would use it like:

```
def some_fun(a, *args, **kw):
    log  = kw.pop("log", None)
    verbose = kw.pop("verbose", 0)
    check_empty_kwargs(kw)
```

calling that with (assuming `debug_log` is defined)

```
some_fun(1, 2, 3, lob=debug_log)
....
TypeError: some_fun() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lob'
```

The traceback will (of course) be different from Python3

Answer (score 1):

You can check against allowed keys, eg:

```
def f(a, *args, **kwargs):
    surplus = set(kwargs).difference(('log', 'foo', 'bar'))
    if surplus:
        raise TypeError('got unexpected keyword argument(s): ' + ', '.join(surplus))
```

Comment: That works. I'll try to upvote this as soon as I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of processing steps, you can combine the above techniques with another one:

```
def f(a, *args, **kwargs):
    # we allow xyz, a, b
    xyz = kwargs.pop('xyz', 1)
    # now xyz must be gone, so we can only have a and/or b
    others = (lambda a=1, b=2: (a, b)(**kwargs))
    # either that was ok or it failed
    return xyz, others
```